# shouldChangeCharactersInRange method not work in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

My method is below, it wrong works, when I write the 22222222222 to TCKimlik text field, it must be write the AdText.text = @"AYŞE"; But this method write AYŞE to TCKimlikText.And the AdText textfield shows empty. How can I solve?

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

if ([[TCKimlikText.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string] isEqual:@"22222222222"])
{   

    cinsiyetBtn.titleLabel.text = @"BAYAN";
    AdText.text = @"AYŞE";
    uyrukBtn.titleLabel.text = @"TC";
    babaAdiText.text = @"KEMAL";
    anneAdiText.text = @"ZELİHA";
    soyadiText.text = @"AYDIN";
    anneKizlikSoyadiText.text = @"DEMİRCİ";
    dogumTarihiText.text = @"01/01/1963";
    medeniDurumBtn.titleLabel.text = @"EVLİ";
    //EsinizinAdiText.text = @"AYŞE";
    dogumYeriBtn.titleLabel.text = @"BURSA";
    kimlikBtn.titleLabel.text = @"Nüfus Cüzdanı";
    //KimlikVerilisNedeniText.text = @"YENİLEME";
    //KimlikVerilisTarihi.text = @"12/01/2010";
    kimlikSeriNoText.text = @"57689";
    vergiKimlikNoText.text = @"45678";
    kimlikSiraNoText.text = @"5443126274";
    yakinlikBtn.titleLabel.text = @"EŞİ";
    kizlikSoyadiText.text = @"YILMAZ";
}

return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested whether your code within the if-clause gets called at all?
If so, check the properties of the XIB-file, maybe the connections between the xib and the code is broken (not linked). Otherwise, try:

```
if ([[TCKimlikText.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string] isEqual:@"22222222222"])
{
    NSLog("Success");
    // Rest of your code...
}
```

to see if your statement is correct.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I checked my connection but all of true connected with textfields :S

Comment: Also it enters the if clause inside. some textfields are changed but only AdText is empty. it writes AdText's string to TCKimlikText.

Comment: Sounds very odd to me. Only valid reason I can think of is the linking with your xib view properties. So that AdText is actually linked to TCKimlikText. However as you have already check this one I can not find any further logic reason why this happens.

Comment: I said that the connections true :S

Comment: Also the when I write 22222222222 the TCKimlikText is AYŞE2 :S